# parse multiple values to user_passes_test in a function-based view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a function-based view

```py
#views.py

def my_view(request,pk):
   post = Posts.get(pk)
   .
   .
   .
    return redirect("my-view")
```

I want to make sure, that the user created the post, also is the one approaching the page.

In the class-based view we can define the `test_func`

```
class MyPosts(UserPassesTestMixin):


    def test_func(self):
        """
        Check if the logged in user is the one created the link
        """
        post= self.get_object() #Gets the current post
        if self.request.user == post.user:
            return True
        return False
```

but I cannot figure out how to parse the `post` argument (or the `post.user`) to the `user_passes_test` function in the function-based view. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) the `user_passes_test` decorator has to take a function which takes a `User` argument as the first arguemnt and two optional arguments - and I need to parse both the `User` and the `post-user` i.e two user objects and not 1 e.g something like

```py
def my_test_func(User,post-user):
    if User==post-user:
       return True
    return False
```

How do I accomplish this w/o using a Class-based view as described above?

Comment: Is using the `user_passes_test` decorator a requirement? Can you not just perform this check in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to check this in the *view* than in a decorator. In that case, we can use the [**`.get_object_or_404(…)`** functin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to check both the primary key and the author in the same query, so something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def my_view(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk, user=request.user)
    # …
```

Comment: In case it cannot be done in the decorator this may then be the best solution (apart from converting to a class_based view maybe)